# Excel - How to search a range for a specific substring and then output the whole value from the cell that the substring was found in?

Tags: excel

I apologize for the long--and possibly confusing--question. I am trying to search a specific range for a substring, and if that substring is found within the range, place the **FULL** value of the cell where the substring was found into a different cell.

For my data set, I have broken up polynomials in such a way that they are listed from least exponent to greatest exponent. Each row contains a different polynomial in this form. The exponents can range from -13 to 16. What I want to do is search through each row individually and sort the data in such a way that the exponent matches which column it is in.

For example, here are some of my data and what I want it to look like after the sorting is complete:

| -13 | -12 | -11 | ... | 15 | 16 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x**(-11) | 3*x**3 | -x**4 | ... | 0 | 0 |
| x**(-12) | -x**(-10) | 1 | ... | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

This table above would turn into the following (with some column heading changed):

| -13 | -12 | -11 | -10 | ... | 16 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | x**(-11) | 0 | ... | 0 |
| 0 | x**(-12) | 0 | -x**(-10) | ... | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

**What I have tried so far:**

I am very new to excel, so I have been aimlessly googling what I think might work and working by trial and error. From what I have tried, the following has brought me closest to what I am looking for:

`=IF(COUNTIF(A3:AD3,"*"& "**4" &"*"),/*TARGET CELL*/, 0)`

where A3:AD3 is a row that I am looking through and "**4" is the exponent I was trying to grab.

I am not sure what to do for the /*TARGET CELL*/ part, though.

Hopefully, my question makes sense. What I want may be impossible, but I appreciate and feedback or any other suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

3 tables : Input tables, 'index' table, 'placement' table

Idea : use index match (or XLOOKUP) with string extraction.

Assume `x**(-11)    3*x**3  -x**4` is in A1:C1 (table 1)

Do :

```
In cell A2 put  =TRIM(A1)
In cell A3 put  =LEN(A2)
In cell A4 put  =FIND("**",A1)
In cell A5 put  =A4+1
In cell A6 put  =RIGHT(A2,A3-A5)
In cell A7 put  =NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A6,")",""),"(",""))
```

and drag all to column C. Then

```
In cell I1 put  3
In cell J1 put  -11
In cell K1 put  4
```

Then

```
In cell G2 put  =IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$C$1,MATCH(G$1,$A$7:$C$7,0)),"")
```

and drag till I2.

table 1 : A1:B1
table 2 : A7:B7
table 3 : G2:I2

by studying the A2:A6 formula you can see that it can easily be combined into one and generate A7:C7 directly.

As you can see, A7:C7 will we the 'address' for the content in A1:C1, given that the G2:I2 column headers (G1:I1) match.

Have a try & share if you get stuck in understanding it (or if it is working in your case).